# convert list of dir paths into a json object

Tags: python, json

I am trying to build a py script that converts a list of paths into a json object as below; the output of the script should be structured as below.
json_out is a list of dictionaries that have four elements (1)type (2)name (3)path and (4)children

```
json_out = [
{
    "type": "folder",
    "name": "dir1",
    "path": "/dir1",
    "children": [
        {
            "type": "folder",
            "name": "photos",
            "path": "/dir1/photos",
            "children": [
                {
                    "type": "file",
                    "name": "mydir1.pdf",
                    "path": "/dir1/photos/mydir1.pdf"
                },
                {
                    "type": "file",
                    "name": "yourdir1.pdf",
                    "path": "/dir1/photos/yourdir1.pdf"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{
    "type": "folder",
    "name": "dir2",
    "path": "/dir2",
    "children": [
        {
            "type": "folder",
            "name": "photos",
            "path": "/dir2/photos",
            "children": [
            {
                "type": "file",
                "name": "mydir2.pdf",
                "path": "/dir2/photos/mydir2.pdf"
            },
            {
                "type": "file",
                "name": "yourdir2.pdf",
                "path": "/dir2/photos/yourdir2.pdf"
            }
            ]
        }
    ]
}    
]
```

This is what I have so far, but this does not return the correct output structure

```
def my_fx(paths):
    for path in paths:
        file_path=path
        l=file_path.split('/')[1:]
        def gen_json(l=l, d=dict()):
            tmp = {}
            if not d:
                d["name"] = l.pop(-1)
            tmp["children"]=d
            tmp["name"]=l.pop(-1)
            return gen_json(l,tmp) if l else tmp
        print(json.dumps(gen_json(l), ensure_ascii=False))
```

My Input

```
list_of_paths = [
        "dir1/photos/mydir1.pdf",
        "dir1/photos/yourdir1.pdf",    
        "dir2/photos/mydir2.pdf",
        "dir2/photos/yourdir2.pdf"
    ]
```

My Output

```
{"children": {"name": "mydir1.pdf"}, "name": "photos"}
{"children": {"name": "yourdir1.pdf"}, "name": "photos"}
{"children": {"name": "mydir2.pdf"}, "name": "photos"}
{"children": {"name": "yourdir2.pdf"}, "name": "photos"}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where does this try to handle `type` and `path`?

Comment: Can you post the input to go with these outputs?

Comment: Edited the input in the question, thanks @Scott